# How do i add pattern in Kitbuilder interface '

Tags: user-interface

anyone who has knowledge about the kit builder? I'm struggling to find out why I can't activate my pattern. I have similar other context, I tried copying it exactly what  the settings are, but I still can't get the pattern to activate, although the kit builder has its own tutorial by their interface,  I still can't get it. Help.

Comment: What is "the kit builder"?

Comment: https://www.kitbuilder.co.uk/#/customise/44626253

Comment: It's a 3d  Custom Clothing Designer Software